# При установке UBUNTU на Prestigio 133s ноутбук происходит ошибка: чёрный экран

Tags: ubuntu, install

Решил освоить OC UBUNTU.

1) Скачал .iso файл с оф.сайта ubuntu.com.
2) Записал образ жесткого диска на Flash - накопитель, она же флешка.
3) Поставил в Bios приоритет загрузки флешки на 1 место.
4) При загрузки просто черный экран или темно-синий и нижнее подчеркивание. Ждал около часу ничего так и не произошло.
5) Пробыл на своем ПК. UBUNTU спокойно загружалась.

p.s Перепробывал практически все программы для записи образа жесткого диска.
Примеры: UltraIso, Rufus тд.тп.

Ноутбук: Prestigio 133s

Comment: Какая видеокарта?

Comment: Видеокарта интегрированная Intel(R) HD Graphics. Дополню что вчера ставить Windows 10. Все прошло гладко. Если необходимо могу скинуть screen, но повторюсь смотреть не на что. Просто черный экран и нижнее подчеркивание.

Comment: У вас выходит меню с пунктами Try ubuntu, install и т.п?

Comment: Нет данное меню не появляется, но на ПК все появляется)

Comment: гугл говорит со стандартным загрузчиком (grub) без чёрной магии на этом ноуте работать не будет (с [uefi](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) связано).

Comment: Вы мне скажите что сделать, я повторю. Очень нужна OC UBUNTU.

Comment: Я думаю этот вопрос решит многие проблемы не только у меня.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вместо вопроса надо было писать баг-репорт разработчикам дистрибутива ubuntu или сразу разработчикам программы linux.

Comment: @ВладиславЧерепня чтобы обойти проблему можно другой загрузчик попробовать. К примеру, [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/index.html). Related: [Any downside to using rEFInd instead of GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/q/760875/3712)

Comment: По-моему в таком случае все ещё можно вызвать меню, только не помню как. Попробуйте TAB. Это всё из-за UEFI, Для создания флешки используйте только то, что рекомендовано на сайте ubuntu.com, там и ссылки на программы должны быть.

Answer (score 1):

По поводу линукса, проблема точно в грубе, кастомная сборка убунты с другим загрузчиком работает нормально, если есть желание можете попробовать.
кастомная сборка убунты 17.10 бета http://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com/
Ссылка на документацию на `isorespin.sh` сборщик кастомных исошек(линукс онли) http://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com/2017/06/customizing-ubuntu-isos-documentation.html

Источник: https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=845227&view=findpost&p=65842147

Да, и в BIOS отключить SecureBoot

Вот тема на 4pda об 57 страницах - https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=845227

Answer (score 0):

## Установка Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS на Prestigio 133s

1. Создать в корне флешки файл с названием `startup.nsh` и содержанием `fs1:\casper\vmlinuz.efi initrd=/casper/initrd.lz boot=casper ---`
2. Проверить: Файлы  `/casper/vmlinuz.efi` и `/casper/initrd.lz` должны находится по этим путям.
3. Загрузиться с флешки(Bios) Built-in EFI Shell.
4. Написать в `Shell>>fs1`:
5. `fs1:>>startup.nsh`
6. Разметить диск и установить Ubuntu
7. А именно Диск C: Взять 128 - 512mb и указать формат efi тип Первичный. А остальное с типом btrfs с точкой монтирования /.
8. В CMD. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rodsmith/refind`
9. `sudo apt update`
10. `sudo apt install refind` В окне указать ДА.
11. Далее опять в CMD. `sudo mcedit /boot/refind_linux.conf` откроется редактор, куда надо написать
    `"ubuntu" "root=UUID=qwe ro rootflags=subvol=@"` где вместо `qwe` надо написать uuid диска, а чтобы его узнать, надо в терминале набрать
    `blkid`
12. также, нужно проверить, чтобы был файл `/boot/efi/EFI/refind/drivers_x64/btrfs_x64.efi` Посмотреть можно в CMD командой `sudo mc`
13. И у вас скорее всего будет отваливатся Wi-fi, чтобы это исправить нужно в CMD написать.

    ```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ryu0/main
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install linux-generic rtl8723bu-dkms
    ```
14. Также Wi-fi отваливается после сна, чтобы не было данной ошибки нужно создать файл командой.

    ```
    sudo mcedit /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wifi
    ```

    с содержимым

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

if [ "$2" = "suspend" ] || [ "$2" = "hybrid-sleep" ]; then
case "$1" in
post)
rmmod 8723bu
modprobe 8723bu
;;
esac
fi
```

p.s Все благодарности говорить данному пользователю https://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showuser=349068

Answer (score 0):

Поставил Ubuntu 16.04.5, установка прошла гладко. Единственное - надо создать EFI-раздел на 200Мб.
Возникла проблема с WIFI - не видит сети. Вот решение:
Ставим драйвер https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu.git
cd rtl8723bu
```

я закоментировал в Makefile строку EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_CONCURRENT_MODE, т.к. иначе создаётся два устройства и у одного постоянно отваливается соединение

```
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -v 8723bu
```

И выключаем драйвер по умолчанию (у меня rtl8xxxu)

```
echo "blacklist rtl8xxxu" | sudo tee --append /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
sudo rmmod rtl8xxxu
```

Comment: ещё упоминается этот репозиторий https://github.com/johnheenan/rtl8xxxu